# how do you add new columns to an empty data frame in R

Tags: r

I declare an empty data frame as this:

```
df <- data.frame()
```

then I go though processing some files and as process, I need to build my `df` data frame. I need to keep adding columns to it:

For example, I process some file and build a data frame called `new_df`, I now need to add this `new_df` to my `df`:

I've tried this:

```
latest_df <- cbind(latest_df, new_df)
```

I get this error:

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :    arguments imply
>   differing number of rows: 0, 1

Comment: Dont' create an empty data.frame first. Just start with new_df and then continue adding any further columns you need. But make sure they have the same number of rows - that's a basic requirement for `data.frame`s. If you need more flexibility, use a `list` instead

Comment: You should make a reproducible example. It's not clear whether each `new_df` will have the same number of rows (in which case the empty `df` is unnecessary) or not.

Comment: check `nrow(latest_df)`and `length(new_df)`. It seems they differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put data into the index after the last column

```
new_df = data.frame()


new_df[,ncol(new_df)+1] = NA
```

So if you knew you had 3 columns then:

```
new_df[,4] = c('a','b','c')
```

Example:

```
new_df = data.frame('a'=NA)
for(i in 1:10){
  new_df[,ncol(new_df)+1] = NA
}
new_df
```

EDIT:

```
ProcessExample <- function(){
  return(c(5)) #just returns 5 as fake data everytime
}

new_df = data.frame(matrix(nrow=1))
for(i in 1:10){
  new_df[,ncol(new_df)+1] = ProcessExample()
}
latest_df <- new_df[,-1]
```

Or just add rows and transpose the data set

```
new_df = data.frame()
for(i in 1:10){
  new_df[i,1] = ProcessExample()
}
latest_df <- t(new_df)
```

Comment: I have to start with an empty data frame, go into the loop, process data and keep adding to the empty data frame. Your answer will not work for what I am trying to do.

Comment: @ChrsityCasey, one row for each column. Latest df should have one row

Comment: Check my answer again, I edited it. That should be what your looking for I think

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want an empty data frame of the proper size before you enter the loop, and assuming "df" and "new_df" have the same number of rows x, try

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=x))

for (i in 1:n){
temp[i] <- % some vector of length x
}
```